# Bootsrap 3 unequal border boldness

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using boostrap 3 and my table borders are unequally bold

my code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

[image]

Is this my display issue?

Or is it css issue?

How to make so that every border line would be equally bold?

Comment: It is maybe because you put `<th>` tags with `<td>` in the same row. Maybe, if you separate these 2 tags, it might fix you problem

Comment: But I need the header to be vertical

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some styles that override the border width.

Here is your example, border-width is just the same:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but when I run your snippet borders show up unequally bolder (bolder border every two rows)

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Microsoft Edge Version 93.0.961.52 and Chrome Version 93.0.4577.82

Comment: well It  happens when I zoom in the page, I don't know why!!